# The origin of the current use of 'readout' in reporting political news

Tags: politics, journalism

The word ‘***[readout](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/readout)***’ has recently started appearing in various U.S. news reports in a sense that seems to be relatively new: a public summary of a meeting, or a phone conversation, which was not itself public (but was not secret either), prepared by (the staff of) one of the parties to it. How did this word end up serving that purpose? What is being *read* here? *Out* of what? Why is calling something a readout supposed to be more useful than calling it a summary or a press release?

> (US) An official statement summarizing the points discussed during a meeting or phone call between diplomats or political figures.
>
> - ‘the White House readout of the call came after the prime minister postponed a key speech on the European Union’

(ODO)

Comment: A "readout" is the value reported by some measuring instrument.  So it's being used metaphorically to mean a somewhat mechanical small bit of reportage.  (Or something the reporter would like you to believe is mechanical, and hence not "colored" by the reporter's prejudices.)

Comment: It is probably an extension of the computer meaning, *the output of information from a computer in readable form.*

Comment: It seems to be more specific than a press release, which is usually a very general announcement about a change or action.

Comment: I think Hot Licks, et al, are correct… and I regret to prophecy it will be no time at all until that "readout" is merged into "read" and hey… we did all see today's difference between "readout" and "read" didn't we?

Comment: It's like takeaway.

Comment: See also [**tick-tock**](https://archives.cjr.org/the_kicker/a_time_for_ticktock.php) as used in journalism for a *timeline-driven narrative.*

Answer (score -1):

I think it comes from a similar government phrase "to be read in" on something. When you "read" someone "in" to a topic, you are providing them with information they need to know. So a "readout" is a more generalized version of that.

Comment: Or it might just be a snappy term for a statement being read out to the people.